# Issue - Kubernetes Deployment with multiple active ReplicaSets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes deployment which is the Owner/Parent of two ACTIVE ReplicaSets with different configurations.

This setup is managed by Helm.

I have tried to make the `revisionHistory: 0`. This doesn't work as the ReplicaSet is not inactive. This old ReplicaSet tries to spin up a pod and it stays in pending because of the resource limitations on the node.

I tried to update the Deployment and only the new ReplicaSet is updated. The old one remains the same.

I am not able to delete this ReplicaSet as well. This is causing a lot of troubles for me.

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Helm Deployment Template -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: example
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: example
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: example
      nodeSelector:
        node-role: example-node
      containers:
      - name: example
        image: example-image:vX.X.X
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - name: example-port
          containerPort: XXXX
        - name: example-port-1
          containerPort: XXXX
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /example
            port: XXXX
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 5
      - name: example-sidecar
        image: example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 400Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: MY_POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        command:
          - command
          - --container=example
          - --cpu=200m
          - --extra-cpu=10m
          - --memory=300Mi
          - --extra-memory=2Mi
          - --threshold=5
          - --deployment=example
```

Stack:  Standalone K8s deployed on AWS EC2s using Kops and Helm 2.13.1

OutPuts -

```
kubectl get rs -o wide -n kube-system | grep example

NAME               DESIRED  CURRENT READY   AGE     CONTAINERS IMAGES SELECTOR
example-6d4f99bc54 0        0       0       12h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=6d4f99bc54
example-59d46955b6 0        0       0       13h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=59d46955b6
example-5855866cdb 0        0       0       18h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=5855866cdb
example-ccc5cf5cd0 0        0       0       18h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=ccc5cf5cd
example-66db79f578 1        1       0       19h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=66db79f578
example-759469945f 1        1       1       19h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=759469945f
example-ff8f986960 0        0       0       19h     example,example-sidecar example-image:vX.X.X,example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X k8s-app=example,pod-template-hash=ff8f98696
```

```
kubectl describe deployments example -n kube-system

Name:                   example
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 03 Mar 2020 00:48:18 +0530
Labels:                 k8s-app=example
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 27
Selector:               k8s-app=example
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 2 total | 1 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           k8s-app=example
  Service Account:  example
  Containers:
   example:
    Image:       example-image:vX.X.X
    Ports:       8080/TCP, 8081/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     1630m
      memory:  586Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        1630m
      memory:     586Mi
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8080/healthz delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
   example-sidecar:
    Image:      example-image-sidecar:vX.X.X
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      command
      --container=example
      --cpu=200m
      --extra-cpu=10m
      --memory=300Mi
      --extra-memory=2Mi
      --threshold=5
      --deployment=example
    Limits:
      memory:  400Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      MY_POD_NAME:        (v1:metadata.name)
      MY_POD_NAMESPACE:   (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:              <none>
  Volumes:               <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  example-759469945f (1/1 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   example-66db79f578 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

```
kubectl rollout history deployments example -n kube-system

deployment.extensions/example 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
16        <none>
17        <none>
21        <none>
24        <none>
26        <none>
27        <none>
```

Comment: what exactly happens when you try deleting the ReplicaSet and how exactly you are trying to delete it? And what is the reason for creating Deployment in `kube-system` namespace?

Comment: @Nick 

When I delete the ReplicaSet, a new one gets spun up immediately with the same Name/ID. I use `kubectl -n kube-system delete rs example-rs-name`. 

Also, the app is in kube-system namespace as the app is related to kubernetes management and not related to Product. We have different namespaces for Product apps in K8s.

Comment: Are you using Helm 2 or Helm 3?

Comment: additionally, if you have installed that rs by Helm - please try deleting it by helm and not via  kubectl

Comment: @Nick 

I am using helm 2.13.1. I have tried deleting the entire Helm Chart and Starting the entire Helm chart. The issue still persist.

Comment: @ArpitAiran Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

We have the similar issue with Openshift that 2 replicasets are owned by the same deployment. And unfortunately, this problem is causing their pods are restarting frequently for about every 100 seconds. This is because the 2 replicasets are using different images. (We are upgrading the image frequently)

There are 2 replicasets (ua-operator-776546f4ff, ua-operator-b6c858456) owned by the same deployment (Deployment/ua-operator). We can see the "restartCount" parameter of pod status is always 0. But the pod can live for about only 100 seconds. It is not caused by app issue. It is the 2 replicasets to do something like rolling upgrade (but not rolling upgrade).

Looking into the 2 replicasets (ua-operator-776546f4ff, ua-operator-b6c858456), you can see they are unfortunately using 2 different images.
replicasets / ua-operator-776546f4ff is using ua-operator:APM_202006202301
replicasets / ua-operator-b6c858456 is using ua-operator:APM_202006212301

While the deployment (Deployment/ua-operator) only specifies the newer image:
Deployment/ua-operator is using ua-operator:APM_202006212301

So the problem is:
Someone created the new Deployment/ua-operator while not completely deleted the old Deployment/ua-operator, so the old replicasets / ua-operator-776546f4ff which was using old ua-operator:APM_202006202301 image was not deleted and is now still there and become a child of the new Deployment/ua-operator. And unfortunately the 2 replicasets are using different images. This is the reason to always restart the ua-operator pods.

I am not sure if it is a Kubernetes or Openshift defect. But we can avoid it by wait the old deployment to be completely deleted then to create the new ua-operator deployment.

Answer (score 1):

**Theory**

> I tried to update the Deployment and only the new ReplicaSet is updated. The old one remains the same.

In this case the issue is that you have 2 different `Deployments`. One that you are editing (so one `rs` gets updated) and another one ("old") that was created in some other way.

Normally, you can't delete `ReplicaSet` easily because it is controlled by another entity.

In Kubernetes it is possible to delete `rs` in a following way:

- Find the name for "old" `rs` with `kubectl get replicaset -n kube-system` .
- Find the object that "old" `rs` is controlled by: `kubectl describe <rs-name>`
- Delete the object that's parent to that `rs`.

**Practice**

The fact that you are observing multiple `rs`'es means that you have been trying updating the `Deployment`.

```
kubectl get rs -o wide -n kube-system | grep example

NAME               DESIRED  CURRENT     READY   AGE     
example-6d4f99bc54 0        0       0   12h 
example-59d46955b6 0        0       0   13h 
example-5855866cdb 0        0       0   18h 
example-ccc5cf5cd0 0        0       0   18h 
example-66db79f578 1        1       0   19h     
example-759469945f 1        1       1   19h 
example-ff8f986960 0        0       0   19h
```

From that output we can see that the `example-759469945f` created 19h ago is alive ( `DESIRED/CURRENT/READY` = `1/1/1` ) . After that there were an attempts to update it, so other `rs`'es were created one by one by update process.

All these attempts were unsuccessful due to an issue with the `Deployment` (we'll discuss that later).

After a few unsuccessful attempts you rolled back to `example-66db79f578` which was created with broken `Deployment` as well (that is why the latest one, `example-6d4f99bc54` has  `0/0/0` instead of `1/1/0`)

That broken `Deployment` is the **root cause** why you have 2 replicasets with `CURRENT`=1  (`example-759469945f` and `example-66db79f578` with `1/1/1` and `1/1/0` respectively).

Please note that the `RollingUpdate` strategy is used in this `Deployment`.

```
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
```

That is why the old `rs` is not decommissioned while new one is not completely "up and running" (has matching values for `DESIRED/CURRENT/READY`)

You'll end up with only one `rs` as soon as you fix the `Deployment` and apply changes .

In order to fix a deployment it is needed to check what went wrong while k8s tried creating a `pod` for `example-66db79f578`

You can do it in a following way:

```
# check the pod name
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep 66db79f578

# describe pod. it shall give you the root cause in "Events:" section
kubectl describe pod example-66db79f578-<somehash>

# additionally you can try checking logs for the containers on that pod.

kubectl logs example-66db79f578-<somehash>  example
kubectl logs example-66db79f578-<somehash>  example-sidecar

# fix :)
# apply changes
```

As soon as you fix the broken `Deployment` you'll be able to apply it with no issues.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The old and new RS are the child of the same Deployment. So if I delete the parent, both the RS are gone. That is the issue, two active ReplicaSet for one Deployment.

Comment: And both replicasets have the same deployment as Parent?

Comment: Yes!!!! That has been the issue since the beginning. Both ReplicaSets have the same Deployment as Parent.

Comment: I'll try reproducing it tomorrow. Are you using gke, eks, aks, standalone k8s?

Comment: I am using Standalone K8s deployed on AWS EC2s using Kops and Helm.

Comment: could you add to your question the output of:
 `kubectl get rs -o wide -n kube-system`, `kubectl describe deployments example -n kube-system `, `kubectl rollout history deployments example -n kube-system` ? I'd like to figure out why that old deployment is created

Comment: I have updated all the outputs that you have requested. Please check.

Comment: Thank you. I was extremely useful. It looks like I've found the issue. Preparing an answer right now. Please check in hour or two

Comment: Thank you for you help Nick. However, I already knew all of that when I posted the question here. The faulty RS is trying to create a pod with more resources than what the EC2 can support and I do not want to change the EC2 size. Therefore, I want some other way to fix the issue. Also, I don't have issue with 2 RS. `The issue is that both the RS have different resource requirements.` Even if I recreate the deployment the issue is not resolved. If there is no other way then I will have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

In you case it would help to specify Deployment [update strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy) explicitly.
From your deployment description we can see the options you are getting by default:

```
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
```

You can see the full YAML using the following command:
`kubectl get deployment example -n kube-system -o yaml --export`

**Note**: `kube-system` namespace is not the best place to put your custom deployments. I would recommend to use a custom namespace created using `kubectl create ns namespace-name` or `default` namespace

There are two ways to fix the issue. You should force the deployment to get rid of the old pod(s) before creating new ones:

**Way one.** Here I've set update type to "Recreate". After being updated, the Deployment kills all pods at once, and starts new version of pods with the same amount of replicas. Some downtime of the service is expected even if the replicas>1.

```
strategy:
  type: Recreate
```

**Way two:** In the next example I've set rolling update options to `maxSurge=0` and `maxUnavailable=1`
After the next update, Deployment will kill one pod as a first step and then creates new version of the pod to keep total replicas count equal to amount set in spec. After the new pod becomes ready, the process will repeat with the next pod. If you have only one replicas some downtime is also expected.

```
strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 0
    maxUnavailable: 1
  type: RollingUpdate
```

Update type explanation:
`k explain deployment.spec.strategy.type`

```
Type of deployment. Can be "Recreate" or "RollingUpdate". Default is
 RollingUpdate.
```

Options explanations:
`kubectl explain deployment.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate`

```
 maxSurge   <string>
   The maximum number of pods that can be scheduled above the desired number
   of pods. Value can be an absolute number (ex: 5) or a percentage of desired
   pods (ex: 10%). This can not be 0 if MaxUnavailable is 0. Absolute number
   is calculated from percentage by rounding up. By default, a value of 1 is
   used. Example: when this is set to 30%, the new RC can be scaled up
   immediately when the rolling update starts, such that the total number of
   old and new pods do not exceed 130% of desired pods. Once old pods have
   been killed, new RC can be scaled up further, ensuring that total number of
   pods running at any time during the update is at most 130% of desired pods.

 maxUnavailable <string>
   The maximum number of pods that can be unavailable during the update. Value
   can be an absolute number (ex: 5) or a percentage of desired pods (ex:
   10%). Absolute number is calculated from percentage by rounding down. This
   can not be 0 if MaxSurge is 0. By default, a fixed value of 1 is used.
   Example: when this is set to 30%, the old RC can be scaled down to 70% of
   desired pods immediately when the rolling update starts. Once new pods are
   ready, old RC can be scaled down further, followed by scaling up the new
   RC, ensuring that the total number of pods available at all times during
   the update is at least 70% of desired pods.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't work as well. I believe somehow the deployment is corrupted and no matter what I do it is not going to get fixed. The only option that has worked so far is that I let the corrupted ReplicaSet run the pods it want to run. In that case the Corrupted ReplicaSet takes precedence and the New ReplicaSet is killed.

Comment: It shouldn't work like that. I would check the kubelet logs on the node ( journalctl -u kubelet ), check the pods state ( kubectl get pods --all-namespaces ), check the description for pods in Pending state ( kubectl describe pod pod_name ), and logs for the failed pods ( kubectl logs pod_name [--previous] ). Nodes available resources would also be informative ( kubectl top nodes ), ( kubectl describe node node_name ). Then I recommend to render helm chart locally and inspect it for duplicate resources or incorrect settings ( helm template ./chart_name > output.yaml ) .

Comment: What is the cluster and kubectl versions? ( kubectl version )